# click <a href> tag and a div slides open to the right, and if <a href> tag is clicked again, div closes to the left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

How would I accomplish this? I'd like to have multiple links...If one is clicked, it slides the div open to the right, if another link is clicked, the first link div would close and the other link div would open displaying different content in each div for each link...Is this possible?

I am new to JavaScript. I am trying to make a `div`, which has an ID of `showcase`, slide open to the right upon clicking a link within `map_menu`. If that same link is clicked again, the `div` slides closed to the left.

I have no idea where to even begin but know I need JavaScript for this.

### CSS

```css
#map_menu {
  width: 250px;
  height: 650px;
  background: #222;
  border: 1px solid #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 16px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}
#map_menu h2 {
  width: 226px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  float: left;
  color: #B45F04;
  font: 24px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000, -2px -2px 2px #000;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(direction=315,strength=2,color=000000);
}
#map_menu a {
  width: 218px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 3px 12px 8px 20px;
  color: #999;
  float: left;
  font: 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000, -2px -2px 2px #000;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}
#map_menu a:hover {
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
  color: #FFF;
}
#showcase {
  width: 710px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #222;
  border: 1px solid #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 12px 12px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 12px 12px 0;
    border-radius: 0 12px 12px 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 58px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="map_menu">
    <h2>Map List</h2>
    <a href="#">• Link</a>
    <a href="#">• Link</a>
    <a href="#">• Link</a>
    <a href="#">• Link</a>
</div>
<div id="showcase">
</div>
```

This is what I got so far using the reference provided by pete, however, it's still not working: http://jsfiddle.net/sej4F/

Comment: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

Comment: have a look at jquery functions like toggle(), addclass, removeclass, there are lots more options.  and if you are trying out a sliding menu, look at 
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/slide-and-push-menus/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can employ jQuery to do something along those lines like this

Javascript:

```
showcase = false;
$('#map_menu a').click(function () {
    $('.showcase-active').hide('slow').removeClass('showcase-active');
    $('.' + $(this).data('showcase')).show('slow').addClass('showcase-active');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="map_menu">
     <h2>Map List</h2>
 <a data-showcase="showcase1" href="#">• Link</a>
 <a data-showcase="showcase2" href="#">• Link</a>
 <a data-showcase="showcase3" href="#">• Link</a>
 <a data-showcase="showcase4" href="#">• Link</a>
</div>

<div class="showcase showcase1">some showcase content1</div>
<div class="showcase showcase2">some showcase content2</div>
<div class="showcase showcase3">some showcase content3</div>
<div class="showcase showcase4">some showcase content4</div>
```

Working example [here]http://jsfiddle.net/dW5ty/1/) - you will have to fiddle with animations etc.  Look at jQuery [toggle documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: This is very close to what I would need.  Is there a way to modify it a bit more, for if the <a> tag is clicked, it opens, then clicked again, it closes...I know this is what you have done, but I guess what I would also need is for if someone clicked let's say the 3rd link - the first link that was clicked prior will close and the 3rd link will open up?

Comment: I have updated the example above to give you more of an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('#showcase').animate({width: 'toggle'});
});
```

Comment: Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/R5byu/1/

Comment: is there a way to make the showcase have different content in it for each link that is clicked?

Comment: You can edit the content inside showcase on the .click method. But for that to work, use a href on the `a` to get the correct element and depending upon the href value, you close the existing div and open a new one. Ping me on a chat if you need any more help

Comment: How would I accomplish that?  I'd like to have multiple links...If one is clicked, it slides the div open to the right, if another link is clicked, the first link div would close and the other link div would open displaying different content in each div for each link...Is this possible?

Comment: I mean it can be done. It will just take a little bit more time :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you test this code..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#map_menu a').click(function(){
            $('#showcase').toggle();
        });
    });
```